# Import date/time field in 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS' format in SAS

Tags: date, datetime, sas, format

I have a .`csv` or .`txt` file which contains a date/timestamp field.
It looks like 'DD/MM/YYYY  HH:MM:SS' in the CSV file. When I load this file is from a txt instead of .csv I can see there is trailing fractional seconds that .csv file isn't displaying.

I want the field to be read in as a date/time field `'DD/MM/YYYY  HH:MM:SS'`  (two spaces between date & time) but cant find the correct format to used.

I'm trying to format this field into a usable format and have tried multiple format types, such as DATETIME19., ANYDTM etc, and I have also tried the picture format < https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Management/Timestamp-format-of-YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS/m-p/314667#M8994>

I currently have the field read in as a character but cant slice the data. Data below is to shown as an example, I'm reading this is from a text file currently.

```
DATA = '2020-08-24 10:49:17.8653230'

DATA ENTITY;
INFILE ENT
    DELIMITER='09'x
    DSD
    FIRSTOBS=2
    TRUNCOVER;

FORMAT CreatedOn $19.;
INPUT CreatedOn $;
RUN;

OUTPUT = '2020-08-24 10:49:17'
```

I've looked through a lot of online resources and must be missing something as I cant make anything I've tried to work.
I want the fields to be recognized as a date&time field with the `DD/MM/YYYY  HH:MM:SS` format instead of a character field.

I'm running base SAS 9.4.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you inspecting your files? Excel interprets your data so its not a reliable viewer for CSV data. Note that a CSV file IS a text file with a csv extension so there should be no real differences.

Comment: Someone else asked a very similar question recently, this isn't a standard date format - so you need to roll your own date informat and then import it or import it as a character, read the date/time part separately and then combine them. https://communities.sas.com/t5/Statistical-Procedures/SAS-datetime/m-p/724644

Comment: Which style is it that you have?  The DMY order in your question or the YMD order in your code block? Is your problem properly converting the strings into the number of seconds since 1960?  Or are you just having trouble displaying the resulting datetime value in that same confusing DMY HMS style?

Comment: @Reeza, thanks for the info re: excel and txt. I have only switched back to text files having encountered formatting problems for date/time fields with excel once a .csv file is opened it converts it formatting. The link you've send me on there has worked and is displaying '01JUL2020:15:12:58' is there a different datetime format I could use instead of datetime19. which would format all elements as numeric. i.e. '01052020:15:12:58', DDMMYYY:HH:MM:SS'

Comment: @Tom, its European DMY order in my code and data. I'm having trouble formatting the long DDMMYYYY:HH:MM:SS as a date time field and not a character string.

Comment: Datetime values are numbers, they are the number of seconds since 1960.  How they are displayed is controlled by the format attached. Once displayed everything is character.  So are you just asking for help with building a custom format that will display datetime values as strings in that style?  If so Reeza's comment above has link to how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Imports fine for me using anydtdtm.

```
data demo;
example_date = '2020-08-24 10:49:17.8653230';
want = input(example_date, anydtdtm.);
format want datetime22.;
run;

proc print;run;
```

Comment: 390194  FORMAT CreatedOn datetime22.;
                                   -----------
                                   48
ERROR 48-59: The format $DATETIME was not found or could not be loaded.

Comment: My version of SAS doesnt seem to have this format type, its an issue I've been having trialing other formats also.

Comment: What's your specific version of SAS, this is using Base SAS concepts which should be available in ALL products. This works and was tested in SAS 9.4M6. Your error indicates a character format/variable so you should show your full code and log.